# Через какое время неактивные чаты автоматически закрываются?

Tags: поддержка, чат

Через какое время неактивные чаты автоматически закрываются?

Мне в самом деле интересно, если активность в чате, скажем С/C++, прекращается, то через какое-то время он автоматически закроется?

Comment: Ирония в том, что для первой публикации обязательно нужно много текста, а потом его можно просто убрать )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, согласитесь, что это не ИИ, а просто дурь.

Comment: это точно не ИИ, а просто набор проверок, довольно прямолинейных и ненадёжных.

Comment: Надо же. И многие с ними согласны? Может без них будет проще?

Comment: на моей памяти раз десять уже на Мете встречалась такая проблема. Даже вроде публиковалось предложение убрать или поменять логику проверок.

Comment: Ладно, подождем ("капля камень точит").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, что через две недели.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно, модератор может разморозить чат, так что не беспокойтесь об этом.

Comment: Отлично. Значит "пинговать" надо раз в 10 дней.

Comment: @avp, не :-) просто когда понадобится - пнуть модератора :)

Comment: [_Rooms not worth retaining which are **inactive for 7 days will be deleted**. Rooms worth retaining which are **inactive for 14 days will be frozen**. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface._](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention)

Comment: Не очень понятно, что означает `worth retaining`, так что лучше пинговать почаще.

Comment: @avp "A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users."

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, надо будет уточнить ответ.